# Which version of mybatis and mybatis-spring jar should be used with spring 3.2.4?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, mybatis

Hi i'm trying to integrate mybatis with my spring application.

I'm using following jars

```
mybatis-3.2.8.jar
mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

I get the following on running my sample java file :

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException.
```

Can anybody tell me which version of mybatis and mybatis-spring jars to be used so that i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think versions are ok check out the sqlSessionFactory as it says some exception related to params.So check the param value passed on for sqlSessionFactory.

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />  
       <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test" />  
       <property name="username" value="postgres" />  
       <property name="password" value="password" /> 
    </bean>
 
    
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

Comment: Amit thanks for the reply i've posted my bean definition. Is there anything wrong in this

Comment: Refer this linke...i hope this will resolve your problem                         http://samuelsimon.me/2014/03/spring-mvc-tutorial-1-simple-mvc-with-postgresql/